# My Macbook Pro M1 2020 won't open with one hand

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

I just bought this laptop 1 week ago. However my Macbook Pro M1 2020 won't open with one hand. Is that normal? Then will it affect the health of the laptop screen?

Comment: If it's too stiff or heavy to lift with one hand, you should take it back to the shop.

Comment: to return to the store took a long time, and I have to use this laptop every day. Is it okay to leave it like that? Will it have an effect in the long term?

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose a potential hardware problem remotely, without much more information. If it is too stiff to lift, and the lower part lifts up as well, then that is not normal. You have paid a lot of money, so you need to check that it is working properly; and that it won't cause a failure later on.